# How to make lungo with Lavazza AModo mio?

Tags: coffee-machines

We bought a new Lavazza A Modo Mio recently, and can’t seem to program it to make a larger cup. It says to hold the button down for 3 seconds and keep holding until cup is full. All it does give small shots which takes endless pressing to fill a cup. What are we doing wrong ?